# Remove old Cipher Suites

Tags: ssl, openssl

I manage some websites and one of them got a poor security rating (from sec scorecard). I have a managed server, so I asked the IT guys to help, but also would like to understand this issue a little more.

The problem is, there are old TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 Cipher Suites, like:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

My first thought, these must be located in the OpenSSL config files. But after some tutorials, I guess it refers to the Apache config.
The `httpd.conf` (and virtual hosts) don't have cipher suites set explicitly. But the included `httpd-ssl.conf` has something.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
 SSLCipherSuite  ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!ADH:!DSS!EXP:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!SRP
```

What I dont understand currently: Is this the right place? Perhaps not or why does this read differently.

I read on ciphersuite.info the first ones above are IANA names (?) and there are OpenSSL names. But what is `ECDH+AESGCM` for example?

Could need some guidance on where to look next. Don't want copy & paste infos, but understand a little more on this topic. However, I am not the security or main IT guy, so I prefer not to read a 300 page book :-/

Comment: ECDH+AESGCM is a cipher suite.  A suite is a asymmetric paired with a symmetric cipher.  In this case Elliptic curve DH and AES-GCM.

Comment: Thanks. But as I understand "TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)" is also called a cipher suite. Right? Why does this not match with anything in my ssl-conf?

Comment: Try Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator. It's a good place to get started: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSLCipherSuite` is the right directive for setting the cryptographic algorithms which should be used. In TLS 1.2, you're expected to set a combination of four algorithms (called a cipher suite):

- A key exchange algorithm which is used to set up a shared secret between client and server. From the secret, both parties can then derive a key for symmetric encryption.
- A signature algorithm for key exchange.
- A symmetric-key algorithm to actually encrypt and decrypt the data which should be transmitted.
- A hash algorithm which is used to ensure the integrity of messages (through a message authentication code) or construct a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator.

Each cipher suite has a unique identifier [registered through the IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) and starting with `TLS_`. For example, there's `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` which stands for:

- The key exchange algorithm is DHE, i. e. Diffie-Hellman key exchange with ephemeral keys.
- The signature algorithm is RSA.
- The symmetric cryptography algorithm is AES with 128 bit keys in GCM mode.
- The hash algorithm is SHA-256.

OpenSSL as a provider of a concrete TLS implementation lets you choose IANA cipher suites through a [custom format called “cipher list”](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT). This format supports complex selection rules like `ECDH+AESGCM` which stands for all cipher suites containing both the algorithms `ECDH` (for key exchange) and `AESGCM` (for symmetric encryption). You can check the exact cipher suites you get with the command `openssl ciphers "ECDH+AESGCM"`. In my case, the list includes, for example, the cipher suite `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` (or as OpenSSL calls it, `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`).

The string `ECDH+AESGCM` itself is **not** a cipher suite. It's an OpenSSL-specific selection rule for cipher suites.

In practice, I would use a concrete list of secure cipher suites, e. g. the [recommendations from Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS). With the OpenSSL selection rules, there's a risk you include cipher suites you didn't actually intend (even though you can always check the result with the `openssl ciphers` command mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes this more clear now. The cipher list link was useful! First half part I knew (kind of) but never reached the depth to get to how OpenSSL works. I am a Web Designer, not a security expert :-D